# Multiple email addresses to one persona

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, subscriber, data-model

We are building a data model in marketing cloud where one individual could have multiple email addresses.  I have referenced the link below but wanted to know if anyone has implemented this type of change?

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/interaction_settings/

We will be changing the subscriber key to the individual ID generated by the data warehouse and therefore will be turning on the EMAIL_SOURCE_DATA business rule to allow one individual to receive an email to multiple email addresses.

The critical unknown is, knowing the email address will not be overwritten in the all subscribers table, will we still be able to achieve tracking through individual sendlogs by job to know which email_address from a data extension received what email?

Answer (score 0):

If your main concern here is tracking of the individual sends, you can achieve it by going to Tracking-->Sends.

Click your email and then click on Total Sent. You will get the result Subscriber Key wise. You can also export this report and further use it.